# How to compile all SASS files in a directory with Elixir?

Tags: sass, laravel-elixir

I'm using elixir to compile my `scss` files.

assuming that this is my folder structure:

```
- app.scss
- header.scss
- footer.scss
- home/
  - home1.scss
  - home2.scss
```

For one file I can use `mix.sass('app.scss');` but what if for all files in my directory without need to add them one by one?

I've tried:

```
mix.sass('*.scss');
mix.sass('**/*.scss');
mix.sass(['*.scss']);
mix.sass(['**/*.scss']);
```

and the only file I can get is the `public/css/app.css`

How can I compile all files in order to get something like:

```
- app.scss
- header.scss
- footer.scss
- home/
  - home1.scss
  - home2.scss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the wildcard solution doesn't work at all.
Have you tried to import your file dependencies, with `@import "file2"`, and only process those files?

Assuming:
home1.scss

```
@import "../app"
@import "../header"
@import "../footer"
// home1 css
```

home2.scss

```
@import "./home1"
// home2 css
```

with:

```
mix.sass('home1.scss');
mix.sass('home2.scss');
```

you'll generate only `home1.css` and `home2.css` with the dependencies style on them.

This way you'll improve your code and get a better control from dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the file globs as an array, like this:

```
mix.sass(['./app.scss', './home.scss'])
```

Or you could import just one sass file in elixir and use the sass import directive in that file to include the rest of the files.

```
@import 'home.scss';
```

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: If I had a lot of files I don't want to have to add them explicitly. Or do it every time a new file is created.
The idea is to use something like `mix.sass(*)`

Comment: The issue is that sometimes you need to specify the files explicitly to make sure they are included in the right order. Take a look at how bootstrap are doing it, for example https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss